# Is 01208 has a special meaning in python or just a bug of python2.6.2?

Tags: python

within python runtime environment, try the following:

```
>> *type(01207)*
```

you'll get:

```
<type 'int'>
```

then try with:

```
>> *type(01208)*
```

you will get:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
type(01208)
         ^
```

Comment: Same way that `type(08)` or `08` is invalid.

Comment: Definitely a bug. I'm afraid that it's in _your_ code, though.

Comment: +1 for considering that it might have special meaning (The same meaning applies to many other languages). It is [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals)

Comment: Any *numeric* value that starts with 0 is an octal (base 8) number, and there is no 8 in base 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it isn't a bug, by prefixing the number with `0` you are using octal and `8` is not a valid digit in base `8`.

```
>>> 07
7
>>> 08
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 010
8
```

Python 3 uses a `0o` prefix (*only* - you can do both in `2.7`) instead to remove this ambiguity.

Comment: it makes sense. and i got the same error with type(0xg).

Comment: It's traditional to prefix octal numbers with `0`, but who uses octal nowadays?